# Contentful Management API upload image

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I'm using the CMA directly (no SDK). I am trying to upload a file to Contenful. From what I've read the flow is this:

1. Upload the file
2. Create an asset(associating it to the recently uploaded file)
3. Process the asset

I am uploading the file like this:

```
const xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 201) {
      let data: any = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
      resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
    } else {
      reject(xhr.response);
    }
  }
};

const url = "https://upload.contentful.com/spaces/" + space_id + "/uploads";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file, file.name);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Then I create the asset like this:

```
const request = {
fields: {
  file: {
    "en-US": {
      contentType: file.type,
      fileName: file.name,
      uploadFrom: {
        sys: {
          type: "Link",
          linkType: "Upload",
          id: uploadId
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

};

```
 return axios
    .post(
      "https://api.contentful.com/spaces/" + space_id + "/assets",
      JSON.stringify(request),
      config
    )....
```

and then process it like this:

```
 const request = {
fields: {      
 file: {
    "en-US": {
      contentType: "image/png",
      fileName: "Sample_45.png",
      uploadFrom: {
        sys: {
          linkType: "Upload",
          type: "Link",
          id:uploadId
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

};

```
 return axios
    .put(
      "https://api.contentful.com/spaces/" +
        space_id +
        "/assets/" +
        assetId +
        "/files/en-US/process",
        asset.data.fields,
      config
    )
```

After that I can see an asset in Contentful Media, but the image never really loads, nor the image size is displayed. It seems like some how Contenful does not recognize the file, or has been incorrectly associated with the asset; I have no clue. Help please.

Comment: That all looks correct. What response do you get if you GET that asset after you process it? E.g., `axios.get("https://api.contentful.com/spaces/" + space_id + "/assets/" + assetId, config)`

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but you don't need to have any body in the `PUT` request to process the asset. One thing that might matter is that when processing the asset you need to include a header `'X-Contentful-Version: 1'` where `1` is the version of the asset prior to processing (normally would be 1 in this flow)

Comment: Yes, I have the `X-Contentful-Version: 1` header. I have removed the body but still the same. I suspect it has to do with the encoding of the file I'm uploading

Comment: I access the newly created asset, I get a normal response, with a file linked, and a url, but when I access the url on the browser, it displays a tiny white square, black background

Comment: what type of file are you uploading? in the processing step Contentful does check the mimetype of the asset and other things to see if it should be processed as an image, etc.

Comment: image/png, I suspect the problem has to do with the way I'm uploading the file, which I do like this:<br/>  `reader.onloadend = () => {
      
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result
      var bytes = new Int8Array(arrayBuffer);
      
      uploadImage(bytes);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)`

Comment: Looking into it a bit more and it looks like `FormData` isn't the right way to upload binary data... can you do `axios.post('https://api.contentful.com/spaces/{space_id}/uploads, file, config)` ?

Comment: Man, that did the trick!!! I would accept your answer, if you publish one. thxs a LOOT!! Literally I've spent the whole day on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using React.

Create an upload form :

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler}>
<button onClick={this.uploadHandler}>Upload!</button>
```

and set your `state`, `fileChangedHandler`, and `uploadHandler`:

```
state = {selectedFile: null}

fileChangedHandler = (event) => {
  this.setState({selectedFile: event.target.files[0]})
}

uploadHandler = () => { 
  axios.post(
    'https://upload.contentful.com/spaces/{space_id}/uploads, 
    this.state.selectedFile, 
    config
  )
}
```

And once the upload is finished, you can create, process, and publish the asset.